# Assembly - Readings strings with scanf in loop only reads one string

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, scanf

I need to read a bunch of strings from command line in assembly, however only one call to `scanf` seems to take place. I'm pretty sure the problem is related to the scanf format. If I replace what I've currently got with a simple `"%s"` it works fine, thing is I have to read whole lines including spaces, so `"%s"` won't do. `"%[^c]s"` should keep reading characters until it encounters `c`, but there's 2 problems with this:

1. I actually have to input the characters `\` and `n` for the scanning to stop.
2. As I said, it only reads one string. After that, all the prompts for the remaining strings get instantly printed at the program ends.

I've seen that people usually suggest using `fread`, however I'm not really sure how to access `stdin` in assembly.

Here's my code:

```
bits 32

global start        

extern exit, scanf, printf   
import exit msvcrt.dll   
import scanf msvcrt.dll
import printf msvcrt.dll

segment data use32 class=data
    msg DB "Enter a value for n", 13, 10, 0
    s_msg DB "Enter a string", 13, 10, 0
    n_format DB "%d", 0
    s_format DB "%[^\n]s", 0

segment bss use32 class=bss
    n DD 0
    s RESB 1000

segment code use32 class=code
    start:
        push    dword msg 
        call    [printf]
        add     ESP, 4 * 1

        push    dword n
        push    dword n_format
        call    [scanf]
        add     ESP, 4 * 2

        mov     ECX, [n]

        read_strings:
            pushad

            push    dword s_msg
            call    [printf]
            add     ESP, 4 * 1

            push    dword s
            push    dword s_format
            call    [scanf]
            add     ESP, 4 * 2

            popad
        loop    read_strings

        push    dword 0  
        call    [exit]
```

Comment: Your assembler does not process `\n`. Try writing that as `"%[^", 13,"]s", 0`. Note that windows uses CR LF which might make your life complicated. Also reading like that will leave the end of line marker in the buffer for the next `scanf`. `fgets` should work better than `fread`.

Comment: @Jester Right. Any idea how/where I could import `stdin` from though?